# Android nullpointerexception in ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I launched my app a few days ago and I can sometimes force a crash by leaving the app with the back button and then opening it a few hours later. It doesn't always do this, in fact it's completely random and 99 out of 100 times it works fine, but I obviously want 100.

This is the relevant bit of my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
            ) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
                {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
                {
                    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
                }
            };
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
       }
}

   @Override
   protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
      drawerToggle.syncState();
   }
}
```

The exception is in the `drawerToggle.syncState();` line. The trace:

```
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.my.my/io.my.my.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()' on a null object reference
    at io.my.my.ui.MainActivity.onPostCreate(MainActivity.java:130)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2675)
    ... 10 more`
```

I could probably solve it by doing the line in a `if (drawerToggle != null)`? But I'd like to know why this is happening and if I'm maybe doing something wrong. It's also pretty hard to test because it's so random.

**Edit**: to make it more clear, I am also using a drawerLayout that is linked to the drawerToggle. According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html:

`Call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.`

That's why I am using onPostCreate. I don't have an onStart.

**Edit** I actually forgot about this bit which I just added to the code:

```
   if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
   }
```

It looks like this is the only possible explanation why drawerToggle is null... but why?

Comment: Not an answer but, why onPostCreate()? Is the code you posted all there is? Is there an onStart()? onPostCreate() runs after onStart()  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: I don't have an onStart, it's not all the code there is but I thought it was all the relevant code. I am using it because I also have a drawerLayout and it says the following on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html: Call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you assign drawerToggle anywhere else in the code? Anywhere at all?

Comment: Just double checked and nope, I don't.

Comment: From the code you posted it looks like `drawerToggle` can only be null in `onPostCreate()` if `onCreate()` was never called, which shouldn't be possible. I'm afraid you'll have to do it the hard way. Plaster your code with debug logs, try to reproduce the error until you succeed, and then look at the logs for anything suspicious. You see anything you can't explain, post it here. You find out what was wrong, post it too.

Comment: I actually just realised this bit might be very relevant: `if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }`. I think this could explain why drawerToggle is null, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Doh! savedInstanceState will be not null every time you're Activity is recreated by the system (but not usually when you use the back button to leave your app), so drawerToggle won't be initialised in that case. I knew there had to be something you weren't showing.

Comment: Just get rid of this: if (savedInstanceState != null) { return; } Not sure what you're hoping to achieve with it anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I took it from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html, it says: `However, if we're being restored from a previous state, then we don't need to do anything and should return or else we could end up with overlapping fragments.`. Do you know why this isn't the case in my example?

Comment: I can't see any notion of a fragment in your code, as is in the link you referenced.

Comment: Yeah I left that out because I didn't want to paste a whole wall of code, didn't think it would be relevant. My mistake. Basically I have 1 activity and a few fragments that I replace in a single container whenever a drawer item is selected.

Comment: Well, in short, if you have member variables, you have to initialise them in onCreate(), every time, or they will be null and referencing them will throw an NPE. Simple as that. And if you don't need to access them, then they don't need to be member variables in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the help!